# Adding Null Date Value in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I'm converting an Oracle database query to a PostgreSQL query. There is a null parameter for date value in the Oracle query. I've searched but I couldn't find anything for PostgreSQL query. What can I use for null date value in PostgreSQL query? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: I'm using Java and the Oracle query is

```
INSERT INTO tableName (name, age, date) VALUES(?,?,?)
```

values are "James", "10", null.

In Postgres query, when I try to give null as parameter, it gives an exception.

Comment: You can use `NULL`.  That is the same in Oracle and Postgres and every other database.

Comment: It would help to see the query and a more detailed explanation of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your answer. I'm using Java and giving null as parameter but it gives me a data exception. Is there a proper way to give null as parameter in Java?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I edited my question and added an example query.

Comment: And the exception is? Is the `date` column in the Postgres table set `NOT NULL`?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the Java code you are using and the exact exception that you get ([edit] your question, don't put code or additional information into comments)

Comment: Does your database column allow nulls? Would you post the table definition? Also what is the message of the exception that you get? Please paste into the question. There’s quite some information that we haven’t got yet that we need in order to be able to help you.

Comment: Also is `date` a reserved word in PostgreSQL, forbidding you to use it in this way in a query?

Comment: @OleV.V. You can use `date` as field name: `create table date_name_test (name varchar, age integer, date date);` ,  `insert into date_name_test(name, age, date) values ('adrian', 39, '11/14/2020'); INSERT 0 1` . That being said I would not to create less confusion down the road.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

- Passing a `null` in Java [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) code as an argument to `PreparedStatement::set…` results in a NULL value in your database row.

  - Exception: If you define your column with `NOT NULL`, then such a submission will of course be rejected by the database system.

## Pass `null` in Java

Your Question is not complete, and should be rewritten per the posted comments.

But I can show some general example code for your perusal. Passing a `null` in Java through JDBC will result in a null value in your database.

```java
pstmt.setString( 1 , "John Doe" );  
pstmt.setObject( 2 , null );        // <-- Passing `null` into the SQL prepared statement.
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Here is a complete example app using the [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)). H2 is a pure Java implementation of a relational database, and can be pulled into the example app like any other dependency.

I expect the same kind of code would run on Postgres.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.sql.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource;

public class ExampleH2App
{

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        ExampleH2App app = new ExampleH2App();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt ( )
    {
        JdbcDataSource dataSource = Objects.requireNonNull( new JdbcDataSource() );  // Implementation of `DataSource` bundled with H2.
        // The `mem` in URL means "in-memory-only".
        // Set `DB_CLOSE_DELAY` to `-1` to keep in-memory database in existence after connection closes.
        dataSource.setURL( "jdbc:h2:mem:h2_example_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" );
        dataSource.setUser( "scott" );
        dataSource.setPassword( "tiger" );

        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;
                // Set `DB_CLOSE_DELAY` to `-1` to keep in-memory database in existence after connection closes.
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
        )
        {
            String sql =
                    """
                    CREATE TABLE person_ ( 
                        pkey_ UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT RANDOM_UUID() PRIMARY KEY ,
                        name_ VARCHAR NOT NULL ,
                        birthdate_ DATE  
                    );
                    """;
            stmt.execute( sql );

            // Insert row.
            sql = """
                  INSERT INTO person_( name_ , birthdate_ )
                  VALUES( ? , ? )
                  ;
                  """;

            try (
                    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement( sql , Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS ) ;
            )
            {
                pstmt.setString( 1 , "Margaret Hamilton" );  // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margaret_Hamilton_(software_engineer)
                pstmt.setObject( 2 , LocalDate.of( 1936 , Month.AUGUST , 17 ) );
                pstmt.executeUpdate();

                pstmt.setString( 1 , "John Doe" );
                pstmt.setObject( 2 , null );  // <-- Passing `null` into the SQL prepared statement.
                pstmt.executeUpdate();

                ResultSet rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
                System.out.println( "INFO - Reporting generated keys." );
                while ( rs.next() )
                {
                    UUID uuid = rs.getObject( 1 , UUID.class );
                    System.out.println( "generated keys: " + uuid );
                }
            }

            // Dump all rows.
            System.out.println( "INFO - Reporting all rows in table `person_`." );
            sql = "SELECT * FROM person_";
            try ( ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ; )
            {
                while ( rs.next() )
                {
                    UUID pkey = rs.getObject( "pkey_" , UUID.class );
                    String name = rs.getString( "name_" );
                    LocalDate birthdate = rs.getObject( "birthdate_" , LocalDate.class );
                    System.out.println( "Person: " + pkey + " | " + name + " | " + birthdate );
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When run:

```
INFO - Reporting generated keys.
generated keys: 386460f8-c2d4-4207-9291-e5aa7eb51471
INFO - Reporting all rows in table `person_`.
Person: ad05fb5e-e731-4a61-ae03-9ed8d9ede100 | Margaret Hamilton | 1936-08-17
Person: 386460f8-c2d4-4207-9291-e5aa7eb51471 | John Doe | null
```

Tip: Avoid naming a column or other object within your database using a keyword such as `date`. Unfortunately, there are over a thousand keywords and reserved words across various database systems. So avoiding all of them is tricky. My solution: I name all my database objects with a trailing underscore. The SQL specification specifically promises to never use a trailing underscore in any naming.

By the way, no need to store age in a table. Given the stored date, you can calculate the age on-the-fly in your SQL query or in your Java code.