# Do you need a database to store data in a java Desktop Application?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am looking to create a BugTracker in java, and since this this a "learn as you go" project I have several questions.

Quick explainer: the app is gonna have a login page and then an interface that sorts text (bug descriptions) into 3 categories (New, In progress, Fixed) now. My questions are:

- Do I need a local database created by the App to store the "Bugs" into categories
- Do I need a local database in order to give different users access to different "bugs" they stored and moved in different categories
- If I do need a local database, how exactly do MySQL and java work together? My program should be able to pull up the database at the click of a button, without having to start up a `localhost`.

As you can tell I'm picking big project for my current skills in order to learn faster, so if you have any other advice on this project or things i should know please let me know.

- yes I know that there is already bug tracking software out there, I want my own" -

Comment: Your question is too broad for Stack Overflow. This site seeks to avoid long-winded or open-ended discussions. For general guidance, use a forums site such as http://www.JavaRanch.com

Answer (score 4):

Using a database is not absolutely needed, but it will make your work much more easy.

But since it's a single user app and only your app will ever access the database, I think using an embedded database, like H2 https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html is the way to go. That way you don't need to run a database server.

But there is one thing you might not have thought about: With your current design you can only ever have one user since the bug database is stored on the local computer and thus only can be accessed by applications running on that computer.

Comment: Agreed. I have posted a few Answers showing a complete example app using H2 to create a database with writing and reading of rows, including [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64840632/642706) yesterday.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will research  embedded databases and H2 in particular. Using a database seems like the smart way to go so i guess after some reading and testing that's what i'll do :) Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

## JDBC

You asked:

> how exactly do MySQL and java work together

MySQL, like any other [relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) ([Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), [H2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)), Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, etc.), talks to a Java app via the [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) framework bundled with Java. You need to provide a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) specific to your particular database.

See the extensive [tutorial on JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/TOC.html) provided free-of-cost by Oracle. See also the sibling site to Stack Overflow, [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

I agree with [the other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64846518/642706) suggesting H2 Database Engine for your needs. [I have written several Answers](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20basil%20H2%20example&t=ipad&ia=web) with code showing how to use H2.

## Embedded mode

You asked:

> My program should be able to pull up the database at the click of a button, without having to start up a localhost.

H2 can be run embedded within your app, as part of your app, sharing the same [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) as your app. Alternatively, you can choose to run H2 in server mode to accept network calls.

The first approach (embedded) suits your needs for a single-user local app. See the documentation, [*Connecting to an Embedded (Local) Database*](http://h2database.com/html/features.html?highlight=embedded&search=Embedded#embedded_databases).

---

Tip: Eventually, once you get the hang of all that, I suggest using a [database migration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration) tool such as [Flyway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyway_(software)) or [LiquiBase](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquibase) to manage your database definition.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer and for the links, i'll make sure to do read them!

Comment: @SebastianMateas I'm glad to have been of assistance. But since you are new to Stack Overflow, let me say that "thank you" messages are generally unnecessary on this site, just clicking the Up Arrow icon button (an up-vote) is thanks enough. This site is designed to avoid chit-chat and discussion. Comments are for clarifications on the material in the Question/Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, do you think of catching just the bugs or the bugs too? In my software I like to use log services, in Spring, I use "Log4j2". I didn't implement a table for errors because it would increase the processing a lot, imagine the amount of unnecessary insertions in the database, and another thing, there will be a lot of try ... catch in your code, so be prepared to handle a lot of kkk errors.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question; they are not talking about detecting bugs in their software, they are talking about building a [defect tracker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bug_tracking_system), where people report issues already found or suspected.

Comment: Hey, sorry of my question was not clear enough. I'm not looking to build a software that auto corrects bugs ( oh my.. how we all wish that would be as easy as it sounds). I'm basically making a more complicated version of the Notes app you have on your phone, where i can keep track of bugs/errors that show up and get fixed along the way. thanks for the reply